# Why are African countries using direct and indirect taxation against their farmers to tax them at a rate twice as high than anywhere in the world?

Tags: economy, taxes, international, policy, africa

Why are African countries using direct and indirect taxation against their farmers to tax them at a rate twice as high than anywhere in the world?

I found this in a research paper entitled [Why kill the golden goose? A political-economy model of export taxation by Margaret McMillan](https://direct.mit.edu/rest/article/83/1/170/57248/Why-Kill-the-Golden-Goose-A-Political-Economy):

> Virtually every country in postcolonial Africa with a major export
> crop has used marketing boards or caisses de stabilisation to tax
> farmers directly by fixing producer prices below world prices. In
> addition, farmers have been taxed indirectly through overvalued
> exchange rates. Table 1 shows that both direct and indirect taxation
> of agriculture has been twice as high in Sub-Saharan Africa than
> anywhere else in the world. Direct taxation, the main focus of this
> paper, has been almost ten times higher in Africa than in Asia, and
> three times higher than in Latin America and the Mediterranean.
> Indirect taxation has been roughly the same in all regions of the
> world.

I was reading it and I was wondering why African countries are imposing such a high tax rate against their farmers through direct and indirect taxation. Is there any motivation for doing this?

Comment: Isn't that answered by [the paper you mentioned](https://direct.mit.edu/rest/article/83/1/170/57248/Why-Kill-the-Golden-Goose-A-Political-Economy)? The conclusion starts off by saying *"Results presented in this paper are consistent with a
model in which the government finds it difficult to commit
to a low-tax policy because farmers incur sunk costs to
produce export crops"*?

Comment: But I haven't seen any explanation as to why African countries are doing this.

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't read the entire paper either but I think the answer may well be in there. Just a hint for future answerers; and feel free to self-answer should you come across a good explanation (in the paper or elsewhere). :)

Comment: Might it be because #1 a lot of people don't hold formal jobs and would be hard to tax otherwise and #2 agriculture is a significant part of African economies?  Besides Africa isn't the only place doing this, so does [Argentina](https://www.world-grain.com/articles/14862-argentina-decides-not-to-increase-grain-export-taxes) and note the reasons given there.

Comment: @Sayaman: In at least some cases (Zimbabwe, for example) it's at least partly because the prosperous farmers are, or were, white.

Comment: @jamesqf Oh, I see, I thought it would be because of something like that.